# Have screen reader pronounce Country codes in a text input as individual letters

Tags: screen-readers, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader, abbreviation

I am working on an Angular app that displays selected Country codes in a text field. This input displays Country codes because of space constraints:

```
<input type="button" #countryListTrigger matInput readonly i18n-placeholder placeholder="COUNTRIES" [ngModel]="selectedCountries" />
```

Here's what the control looks like with Country codes displayed:

[Countries Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkl8o.png)

Right now, screen readers would read the AU like the letter "o" and AT like "@".  I know about the  tag, but is there a way to achieve the same result on an input value?  Otherwise, I could add another (hidden) control that is read instead perhaps?

Comment: Is ARIA already abandoned for web?

Answer (score 1):

It starts getting messy if you try to force a screen reader to announce things phonetically.  If you add an `aria-label` that has `aria-label="A U"` or `aria-label="A T"`, then braille users will be out of luck because they'll read "A space U".

It's unfortunate there isn't really a good solution for this.  The screen reader user can read the input value one character at a time so if it sounds weird to them, they have a work around.  It's not a great user experience but having screen readers mispronounce stuff has been a problem for a long time.